# Handlebars variables

Tags: html, node.js, pug

I want converting a code from jade to html to use on hbs file with node i noticed that on jade you can create variables like that on jade

```
   - var x = 1
```

i want to know how to convert the varibale to html with handlebars templating language i know how to convert if statments and other lines but how to convert variabales ?

my full code

```
if pageCount > 1

      ul.pagination

       if currentPage > 1
        li

          a(href='/?page=1')  &laquo;

       - var x = 1

       if currentPage > 5

         - x = x + (currentPage - 4)

       if (x !== 1)

           li.disabled
              a(href='#') ...
       - for (x; x <= pageCount; x++)

           if( currentPage == x)

            li.active
               span.sr_only
                   = currentPage

           else
             li
               a(href= "/?page=#{x}" )
                = x
           if x == (currentPage + 4)
               li.disabled
                a(href="#") ...
                - break

        if currentPage != pageCount
          li
            a(href= "/?page=#{Math.floor(pageCount)}" ) &raquo;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit different in Handlebars if you wanna Implement JavaScript Code you should make a custom Helper or if you gonna render some DOM to the screen you can make a partial you'll find all what you may need in Handlebar's official documentation.
[Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/)